# Translating python function with boolean indexing within loop to cython

Tags: python, cython

Below I'll write a function in pure python that I want to Cythonize.

```
def do_stuff(M_i, C_i):
    return M_i.dot(C_i).dot(M_i)

def foo(M, C):
    '''
    M : np.array
        N x J matrix
    C : np.array
        J x J matrix
    '''

    N = M.shape[0]

    tot = 0

    for i in range(N):
        nonmiss = ~np.isnan(M[i, :])
        M_i = M[i, nonmiss] # select non empty components of M
        C_i = C[nonmiss, :] # select corresponding components of C
        C_i = C_i[:, nonmiss] # select corresponding components of C

        tot = tot + do_stuff(M_i, C_i)

    return tot
```

Suppose that I know how to Cythonize the function `do_stuff`. The actual `do_stuff` function I'm interested in is more complicated than the one above but I thought I'd provide an example. The real `do_stuff` function computes determinants and takes inverses, in addition to matrix multiplication.

My main problem has to do with creating the `M_i` and `C_i` subvector and submatrix. I'm not sure I can do the same sort of boolean indexing in Cython. And if I can, I don't know how. But I can get started with the bit of Cython I know.

```
def foo_c(double[:, ::1] M, double[:, ::1] C):

    cdef int N = M.shape[0]
    cdef double tot = 0
    ...

    for i in range(N):
        ...
        tot = tot + do_stuff_c(M_i, C_i)

    return tot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't gain *too* much speed here, since boolean indexing in Numpy is implemented in C anyway, so should be fairly fast. The main thing you'd avoid is creating some unnecessary intermediates (which involves a memory allocation so is potentially slow).

What you want to do is create temporary arrays for `M_i` and `C_i` that are the largest possible size (i.e. `J` or `JxJ`). As you iterate through `isnan(M_I)` you keep track of how many values you've actually stored. Then at the end you trim `M_i` and `C_i` to only the part that you've used:

Untested code:

```
for i in range(N):
    filled_count_j = 0
    M_i = np.empty((M.shape[1],))
    C_i = np.empty((M.shape[1],M.shape[1]))
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        if ~isnan(M[i,j]):
            M_i[filled_count] = M[i,j]

            filled_count_k = 0
            for k in range(M.shape[1]):
                if ~isnan(M[i,k]):
                    C_i[filled_count_j,filled_count_k] = C[j,k]
                    filled_count_k += 1
            filled_count_j += 1
     M_i = M_i[:filled_count_j]
     C_i = C_i[:filled_count_j,:filled_count_j]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are ready to work with pure arrays, you can get a bit of speed up (maybe 1.2x-5x) by cythonizing all your code. But it's probably not worth the time that you will spend, loosing the convenience of numpy. It depends what's the priority in your project and how heavy is your do_stuff() function.